# Как поменять при запуске программы запускаемое окно на другое?

Tags: c#, wpf

Запускается окно первым Window1.xaml.

Но надо поменять на WindowStart.xaml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исходя из вопроса, предположу, что вам нужно в App.xaml поменять `StartupUri` с `Window1.xaml` на `WindowStart.xaml`.

Если у вас много окон в приложении, возможно, вам стоит обратить внимание на `ShutdownMode`.